# How to find two groups from same string using single regex?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I was experimenting with regex and stuck with the following problem.

Say, I have a string `I am batman`

How can I capture `bat` in one group and whole of `batman` in another group?

The word can be anything..

Example:

```
I am batman
I am superman
I am ironman
```

Output

```
bat and batman
sup and superman
iro and ironman
```

I tried `I am (\w{3}|\w*)` but it is capturing only one group (1st).

Is it even possible what I am trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
I am ((\w{3})\w+)
```

it captures whole word first and first three characters in the second group

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qH2lD5/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php
$string = 'I am Ironman';
preg_match('/I am (\w{3}).*(man)/', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

The output is:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "I am Ironman"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "Iro"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "man"
}
```

What you want will always be in the first and second ([1] and [2]) indexes of `$matches`.

Comment: I don't think you read my question properly.. 2 should be `Ironman`.. Thanks for your efforts.. :)